# CoreData - recreate persistent store after broken database

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to implement method, that will recreate new persistent store, when store will be broken due to failed migrate or save. I have following code:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "test")
container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
    if let error = error {
        do {
            try container.persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL(), ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil)
                // what to do here?
            } catch let error {
                print ("\(error)")

            }
        print("Unresolved error \(error)")
    }
    })
    return container
}()
```

I implement destroying persistent store, when it is broken, but I cannot find something useable in documentation, which method can recreate that. Maybe somebody have this type of problem?

Comment: any suggestions for now?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [CoreStore](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore) to manage your CoreData. It automatically recreates your database if an error occurs. If you start initializing your database with the following code, it will also check your current status and repair everything if possible:

```
let dataStack: DataStack = {
    let dataStack = DataStack(xcodeModelName: "ModelName")
    do {
        try dataStack.addStorageAndWait(SQLiteStore(fileURL: storagePathUrl, configuration: "Default", localStorageOptions: .
            recreateStoreOnModelMismatch))
    } catch let error {
        print("Cannot set up database storage: \(error)")
    }
    return dataStack
}()
```

Comment: I try to use this library, but when I will be using DataStack, I cannot use it like typical CoreData stack and use native types. Maybe is there some another way?